# Rails db:migrate aborted with "undefined local variable or method `limit'" why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, methods, undefined, dbmigrate

Sorry for my English.
I searched the site, but I could not find a solution.
When I try to make rails db: migrate gives me this error:

```
C:\PW\Sites\grota>rails db:migrate
== 20170209014957 CreateWholesalers: migrating     ================================
-- create_table(:wholesalers)
-- limit()
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method `limit' for #    <CreateWholesalers:0x00000006bfc6a0>
C:/PW/Sites/grota/db/migrate/20170209014957_create_wholesalers.rb:7:in     `block in change'
C:/PW/Sites/grota/db/migrate/20170209014957_create_wholesalers.rb:3:in     `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
NameError: undefined local variable or method `limit' for #    <CreateWholesalers:0x00000006bfc6a0>
C:/PW/Sites/grota/db/migrate/20170209014957_create_wholesalers.rb:7:in     `block in change'
C:/PW/Sites/grota/db/migrate/20170209014957_create_wholesalers.rb:3:in     `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

here is my migrate code:

```
class CreateWholesalers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :wholesalers do |t|
      t.string "brand_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest"
      t.string "email", limit => 50
      t.decimal "latitude"
      t.decimal "longitude"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the error (missing `:`):

```
t.string "email", :limit => 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Cristiano Morais should be marked as correct answer. It is a spelling mistake. Missing **:**